# I have 4 different color health bars stacked on top of each other and need pseudo code to make them work together

Tags: javascript, c#

I have 4 health bars stacked on top of each other each a different color

I want the top health bar to represent 50% of the players health
 and to shrink from 1 to 0 based on the current health,
 reaching zero when the health is at 50%
So 100 health would be 100 percent of the first bar, 
75 health would be 50% of the first bar 
and 50 health would be 0 percent of the first bar.

Then the second bar I would like to represent 30% of the players health 
and start where the 50% ends.

Third bar going down after 80% of the health is gone and representing 15% of the total health and finally the 
fourth bar representing 5% of the total health starting when 95% of the health is gone.

I cant even get the first bar to represent 50% of the players health and go down to 0 when the player reaches 50% health so if anyone would even know what the pseudo code for that would be I'd greatly appreciate it

Hope this question isn't too poorly written out and that I don't waste anyone's time.. I've just been working on this for a few hours now and getting no where.

I know how to make a single health bar representing 1 to 0 as Healthlength = FullLength/ FullHP * CurrentHP but that isn't getting me anywhere

example

FullLength = 1; //0 is completely slide to the left

FullHP = 100 //for example

CurrentHP = 50

this would returen HealthLength as .5 or half.

That about covers everything I can think to include in my question, I hope someone can help.
Thank you for your time.
Note: I included javascript and c# because those are the only two languages I kinda know and I don't see a pseudo code option

Comment: If you have difficulty in putting your idea into words, maybe create some images showing what you are trying to achieve, even hand drawn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generalise an answer to this, I'll work through how I made the formula to calculate a bar's length. The length will be a float from 0 - 1.

To calculate the bar's length, you need 3 values

- The bar's maximum value: `barMaximum`
- The bar's minimum value: `barMinimum`
- The player's current `health`

To begin with, lets imagine the second from top bar (shown in blue). It has a `barMinimum` of `20`, and a `range` of `30` (To get the range, subtract the minimum from the maximum).

[image: 4 health bars]

What the formula will do is *move* and *scale* the blue bar's range to fit in our desired range (in this case 0 - 1).

Picture the (poorly drawn) number line below:
[image: blue bar number line]

We see the blue bar ranges from 20 to 50, and our desired range is from 0 to 1. This blue bar represents the *range of values* that the player's health could be. The first thing we want to do is *move* it to our desired range.

We know the distance from the start of the blue bar the start of our desired range, as it is just the blue bar's minimum value (in this case its 20). So to move the blue bar to the start of our desired range, we need to *move it left 20 spaces*. And to move it left 20 spaces, we need to subtract 20 from it.
[image: moving blue bar left 30]

Don't forget that this bar simply represents the range of values that `health` could be, which is why I have named the variable `movedHealth`. To put this action into code, we could say:

`movedHealth = health - 20;`

And to generalise this (so it can be used for any bar) we could say:

`movedHealth = health - barMinimum;`

Okay, so now we have *moved* the blue bar into the correct place. Now we need to *scale* it so it fits within our desired range. As we are scaling, we can assume that we will need to use multiplying or dividing for our next move. But how can we find out what we need to multiply/divide by?

What we can do is look at a few examples of where we know our blue bar (which now represents `movedHealth`) will move.

We know that if `movedHealth` is half way through our blue bar (in this case 15), we want it to be half way through our desired range (which is 0.5). Another example: if `movedHealth` is at the moved bar's maximum (30 in this case), we want it to be at our desired range's maximum (which is 1).

Lets use the latter example to help us calculate our scale. We can use some simple algebra to figure out what to do here. We know that our moved bar's maximum value is 30, and our desired range's is 1. So the moved bar's maximum is *30 times* our desired range's maximum

`moved bar's maximum = desired range's maximum * 30`

We can then generalise this for any value:

`moved bar = desired range * 30`

So this means that if we wanted to scale *up* a value from our desired range (0 - 1) to our moved bar, we would *multiply* it by 30. Therefore, if we wanted to scale *down* a value from our moved bar to our desired range, we would *divide* it by 30:

`desired range = moved bar / 30`

This can be visualised on our number line:

[image]

To re-iterate, to scale a value from our moved bar (0 - 30 here) to our desired range (0 - 1), we divide it by 30. This means that we can replace the "moved bar" part of our equation with `movedHealth`, since the bar is just representing the values `movedHealth` could be:

`desired range = movedHealth / 30`

And now that we have scaled down our `movedHealth` to our desired range, we can replace "desired range" with `scaledHealth`, since we have scaled down its possible values to the range of 0 to 1.

`scaledHealth = movedHealth / 30;`

Now we have this equation for this specific example, lets generalise it to fit any bar. The only part we need to change is the 30. This 30 came from the bar's maximum value *after* being moved. If we look at the diagram below we can not only see the progression of the blue bar, but also the links between certain aspects.

[image: changes to the bar]

For example the fact that moved bar's maximum value, is equal to its range. This is because:

`original bar's maximum = 50`

`original bar's minimum = 30`

```
original bar's range = original bar's maximum - original bar's minimum
= 50 - 20
= 30
```

And when we look at how we calculated the moved bar's maximum value, we subtracted 20 (the original bar's minimum) from the original bar's maximum value. When visualise this in an equation we see:

`moved bar's maximum = original bar's maximum - original bar's minimum`

Which is *identical* to how we calculate the original bar's range. So because of this, we can now replace the "30" in our `scaledHealth` equation:

So

`scaledHealth = movedHealth / 30;`

becomes

`scaledHealth = movedHealth / barRange;`

And since `scaledHealth` is actually the length of the bar (from 0 - 1) we should probably replace it with a more fitting name, such as `barLength`. So:

`barLength = movedHealth / barRange;`

Now lets put all our code in one place:

```js
movedHealth = health - barMinimum;
barRange = barMaximum - barMinimum;
scaledHealth = movedHealth / barRange;
```

To put this into one equation, we can first substitute any reference of `movedHealth` with `(health - barMinimum)`, so we get:

```js
barRange = barMaximum - barMinimum;
scaledHealth = (health - barMinimum) / barRange;
```

And now we can substitute any reference of `barRange` for `(barMaximum - barMinimum)`, so we get:

`barLength = (health - barMinimum) / (barMaximum - barMinimum);`

And don't forget that this doesn't account for values of `health` which are outside of the bar's range. So to counteract this, we could do something like this:

`Math.max(0, Math.min(1, barLength));`

So now we can write a function, using this new found equation:

```js
var health = 35; // can be ANY value, just put 35 as an example
var barMinimum = 20; // replace with whatever the current bar's minimum is
var barMaximum = 50; // again, replace with the bar's maximum

function calculateBarLength(health, barMinimum, barMaximum) {
    return Math.max(0, Math.min(1, (health - barMinimum) / (barMaximum - barMinimum)));
}

var barLength = calculateBarLength(health, barMinimum, barMaximum);
console.log(barLength);
// outputs 0.5
```

Vuala!

This is very similar to scaling a number between to ranges. For example [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224535/scaling-between-two-number-ranges).

Comment: thank you so much for all your hard work Dan!