# Is there a javascript substitute for numpy.interp()?

Tags: javascript, numpy

I need the functionality of `numpy.interp()` from python in javascript.

Example - how do i implement this in javascript ?

```
result = np.interp(5,[0,10],[0,100])
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve it on your own?

Comment: I know that something basic like this would work for now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224535/scaling-between-two-number-ranges I'm just cusiouse, if there is a "proper" numpy-like library, that is also able to do more advanded stuff.

Comment: _"if there is a "proper" numpy-like library"_ - Asking for a library (or other off-site resources) is off-topic for SO

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what `numpy.interp()` is but I can Google it. Looks like it is:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html

> One-dimensional linear interpolation.

Then we Google `javascript One-dimensional linear interpolation` and the first result is:

http://borischumichev.github.io/everpolate/

Cool! Yeah, I think there are libraries for what you would like to do.

Comment: Instead of adding an answer to an off-topic question you should vote to close it -> [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)